# UITableViewCell selection Storyboard segue is slow - double tapping works though

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, ios8

I have a UITableViewController in a Storyboard. I have the selection of my UITableViewCell prototype trigger a segue to present another controller. The presentation itself is working.

I noticed a strange bug (possibly introduced in iOS 8) that tapping on the cell highlights the cell as expected but sometimes takes several seconds before performing the segue. Tapping on the cell twice causes the segue to happen immediately.

Has anyone else noticed this in iOS 8?

EDIT: I've now noticed that it is not just a double tap that triggers the segue faster. It is also a tap on the cell followed by a swipe anywhere. Starting to seem like a threading issue to me...

Comment: No code whatsoever, just segue in storyboard? What happens if you add `performSegue` on `didSelectRow`? PS: I hate using segues, the only reason I add them is to mark the flow of the application.

Comment: Yea, I'd post code, but there is none, basically. Tried what you said, same issue.

Comment: You must be doing something. I tested with old projects as well as created a new one, but there's no delay between selection and push, just like before iOS8.

Comment: I have the same issue and i can't understand why is this happening. i´ve tried with different segues and with performSegue but nothing solves the problem. This only happen if Table View Cell selection is set to none, otherwise works fine.

Comment: I posted what ended up being the solution to my case. Thanks to @LordZsolt for the inspirado in trying that again.

Comment: I'm also curious if the solution fixes your problem as well, @CarlosVela

Comment: In the initial case, it'd be interesting to know on what thread `performSegue`/`prepareForSegue` get executed on.

Comment: I was interested too, so I definitely looked into it while I was debugging this. I wasn't called `performSegue` manually before- it was done in Storyboard by connecting my cell prototype's `selection` outlet to a modal segue (so I couldn't look into `performSegue`). However, I did try calling `[[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]` from inside `prepareForSegue` which returned `YES`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my case, the solution ended up being to call `performSegue` manually from `didSelectRow` on the main queue using GCD instead of using the `UITableViewCell` selection outlet in Storyboard.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kShowDetailSegue
                          sender:nil];
  });
}
```

I'm not sure why this became necessary- certainly you'd think that the selection outlet in Storyboard would operate on the main queue, but maybe it is an iOS 8 bug.

Comment: If you want this segue to behave the same way as the original segue.  Instead of `sender:nil` use `sender:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.  This will mean in prepare for segue you can use the sender to determine the indexPath as is often necessary when setting up the destination view controller.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where programmatically calling performSegueWithIdentifier would take literally 10+ seconds before actually loading the next view.  Not sure what sort of thread nonsense was going on behind the scenes, but dispatching on the main queue solved my problem as well.

For what it's worth, I was making significant use of multipeer connectivity (and not really much else); not sure if that's related.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple did not fix this bug yet! Still happens in iOS 9!

Comment: iOS 10.3, bug still there. Blank project, only UITableViewController with basic cells and VC to segue to. Setting the cells property  'selection' to none, causes sometimes issue of segue not being called (usually after scrolling table). didSelectRow is being called always. Segue is connected directly from cell to another VC. Just putting DispatchQueue.main.async {} (passing empty block) in didSelectRow, solves this issue.

Answer (score 4):

[Carlos Vela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1992147/carlos-vela) is right, the bug is accouring only when UITableViewCell selection is none and only on real device. Waking up CFRunLoop after selection solves the problem and this led me to this "universal" workaround (which is a category on UITableViewCell).

UPDATE: it works perfectly under iOS7 but under iOS8 it brokes transparent UITableViewCell background (it will be white).

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITableViewCell (WYDoubleTapFix)

+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod([UITableViewCell class], @selector(setSelected:animated:));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod([UITableViewCell class], @selector(mySetSelected:animated:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (void)mySetSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self mySetSelected:selected animated:animated];
    CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

@end
```