# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath sometimes called after second tap

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, segue

I'm facing a curious `UITableView` behaviour and i don't know where this is coming from.
I'm building a very simple single view IOS8 Swift application with a first `ViewController` with a `UITableView` inside it and one custom Image cell. When i tap on a cell it Segue to my `SecondViewController`.

My UITableView delegate and datasource is connected to the first ViewController.
Everything is working except when i tap a cell sometimes i have to tap it twice to trigger the Segue.

Here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You clicked on \(indexPath.row) row")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeToDetail", sender:self)
}
```

My print is always returning the correct indexPath.
Is it a view hierarchy problem or something else ?

Thank you JD

Comment: Interesting, can you share a little more code? is this on the simulator or real device?

Comment: simulator and real device

Comment: Does the `println` get triggered only once, or twice?

Comment: If I were you the quickest way to find out what's happening is to step through the function calls

Comment: Do you have `allowsMultipleSelection` set to true?  If so it might be treating the first tap as DEselecting the row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("homeToDetail", sender:self)
  })
}
```

This is a bug in iOS 8, I think. [UITableViewCell selection Storyboard segue is slow - double tapping works though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165700/uitableviewcell-selection-storyboard-segue-is-slow-double-tapping-works-though)

Comment: Interesting, so pushing the call onto the main queue is a workaround for the bug?

Comment: That's what worked for the other two guys. weird though.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` to fix this