# segue not called immediately

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller A and it has a table list created dynamically with cells
when calling didselectcell as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if(cell?.tag == 1){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender: self)
        print("perform segue for favourite")
    }
```

and i am calling prepare for segue like this and saving the variable the variable is available in 2nd view controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if(segue == "profile"){
     let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MembersViewController
                    vc.title = " "
  }
```

when i run the app it takes hardly more than 25 sec [ the second view controller has collectionview] any idea of doing it  faster

Comment: I would guess that the logic you have in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppeare ( or collection view delegate method ) takes time which slows down the 2nd view to appear on the screen.

Comment: You could use Instruments > Time Profiler to find out.

Comment: @Greg i have nothing in viewdidload and a for loop in viewdidappear in 2nd view controller

Comment: It's difficult to say something with no seeing the code. Post code from your viewDidAppear method.

Comment: @Greg i have removed the loop and tested the same issue exists

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling dispatch_async function it moves immediately to next page and the next page also has for loop in viewwillappear thanks @rakeshbs got answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906793/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-sometimes-called-after-second-tap)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
if(cell?.tag == 1){
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender:self)
        })
}
```

Comment: See my answer below. This is not needed, and is messy code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this. Change your `didSelectRow` method to this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("profile", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

You can fix your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to remove needing to grab the cell. It has a reference to the cell's index already, which is what you were grabbing.

Also, your `prepareForSegue` method can be improved as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "profile") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? MembersViewController
        vc?.title = "New Title"
    }
}
```

You should never need to call `dispatch_async` with something like this, especially in Swift, unless you're already on a Background thread.

Before using the `UITableView` object and its `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` components, I suggest you muck about in an Xcode Playground, and read the Apple Documentation carefully to understand how everything works.