# UIPresentationController is being presented after huge delay

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I present my custom `UIPresentationController`:

```
func presentOverlayController(controller: UIViewController) {

    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    controller.transitioningDelegate = self

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return OverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
```

I present my controller once I tap on `UITableViewCell`. It is presented very quickly only if I tap on cell twice. However, when I perform single tap, then it works as well but with huge delay (between 15-60 seconds).

**What is the reason?** 
How to workaround it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that occurred to me as well, and this is the workaround I used.

Try to do this inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    presentOverlayController(......)
})
```

References:

- [UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath sometimes called after second tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906793/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-sometimes-called-after-second-tap)
- [UITableViewCell selection Storyboard segue is slow - double tapping works though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165700/uitableviewcell-selection-storyboard-segue-is-slow-double-tapping-works-though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```