# iOS: didSelectRowAt Index Path only works on second click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am struggling with an issue on my xcode project. I'm displaying custom cells in a table view and using `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` to show a detail view. It works the way I want to, but weirdly only on the second click.

I am fairly new to programming and would appreciate your help with this. Thank you so much!

I checked that I'm not using `didDeselectRow at` by accident. I also went through stackoverflow to try and find a solution, and that was the closest I could find to my issue. But I am using `didSelectRow at`.

// Here is my code for when the user taps a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Pop Up Variables

    var id:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_id!
    var title:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_title!
    var type:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task!
    var desc:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_desc!
    var action:String = "Dismiss"


    present(detailVC!, animated: true, completion: {
        self.detailVC!.setPopup(withTaskId: id, withTitle: title, withType: type, withDesc: desc, withAction: action)
         })



}
```

// Just a note here,I am setting up the switch to the other view controller at the top of the document.

// Display the popup
    var detailVC:TaskDetailViewController?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up the task detail view controller
    detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TaskDetailVC") as! TaskDetailViewController?
    detailVC?.delegate = self
    detailVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    // Conform to the table view protocols
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    // Set Self as delegate for model and call getTasks

    // Get the Tasks from the Task Model
    model.delegate = self
    model.getTasks()


}
```

The detail view only appears after I tap a row the second time. Not the first time?

Comment: Try to avoid *snake case* in Swift: `task_id` —> `taskId` or better, just `id`

Comment: You more than likely have another gesture recognizer conflicting with the tap on cell.

Comment: Please confirm- Hard press a cell and check, is it clicking on the first attempt?

Comment: Maybe start by setting a breakpoint (or if you're not sure how, just a log message) and make sure that `didSelect` is properly called every time you tap on a cell. It would also help if you could give us more details about your setup/view hierarchy. For example, is your `tableView` the top-level view?

Comment: Happened to me several times when I was new to iOS because I used `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` instead. It's probably not your case but as other suggested, put breakpoints in various places. Or you can upload the whole project and we can try to fix that

Comment: Thanks for all this feedback, I managed to get this resolved (see answer from koropok). Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a few years back, didn't know that it still persist today.

I solved it by encapsulating all logic within `didSelectRowAt` in the main thread using GCD. You can check these out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907119/6642629

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26183438/6642629

You can try the following:

**Swift 4**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        var id:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_id!
        var title:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_title!
        var type:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task!
        var desc:String = tasks[indexPath.row].task_desc!
        var action:String = "Dismiss"

        present(detailVC!, animated: true, completion: {
            self.detailVC!.setPopup(withTaskId: id, withTitle: title, withType: type, withDesc: desc, withAction: action)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, I just had to use the self keyword on your code to get it to work, but it worked now. Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Selection` of your UITableView in InterfaceBuilder from `Multiple Selection` to `Single Selection` and it will works as you wish.

Then you should handle selected state of each row on your own (using a field in model or set color for background or etc)

[image]